# How can I use Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials to factor polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring, symmetric-polynomials

> How can I use [The fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) (or its proof) to factor symmetric polynomials?

The link I've given to the theorem uses elaborate wordings using 'rings', 'isomorphic', etc.

I completely understand those objects or describings are needed to have a deep understanding, but could anyone try, if it is possible, to explain simply how I could use the theorem to, e.g., factor

$(a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)-(a^3+b^3)^2 = a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2ab)$

without understanding what rings are? I only wish to be able to practically use it.

Comment: To clarify - the 100 bounty is only there to draw attention. I'm not sure if this is a difficult question to answer (I have zero understanding of the theorem), but I gave it a bounty since there were no responses at all. I don't have high requirements for the answerer. But I do really want to be able to factor symmetric polynomials practically, like the polynomial in the question description. It looks very useful.

Answer (score 7):

> **Note:** As already noted by  @ZilinJ  the *[Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials)* guarantees the *unique* representation of symmetric polynomials $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ as polynomial $Q$ in the *elementary* symmetric polynomials $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ in $n$ variables
>   \begin{align*}
> P(x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n)=Q(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)
> \end{align*}
>   with
>   \begin{align*}
> e_1&=e_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n\\
> e_2&=e_2(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\cdots+x_{n-1}x_n\\
> &\ldots\\
> e_n&=e_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_1x_2\cdots x_n
> \end{align*}

$$$$

> This answer introduces a method to *systematically* transform a symmetric polynomial into a polynomial representation by elementary symmetric polynomials. It's based on *Paul Garrets* algebra course section $15$ *[Symmetric polynomials](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/15.pdf)*.
>
> Let's start with OPs example and then continue with a slightly more complex one in order to better see how the method works.

OPs symmetric polynomial $P(a,b)$ is

\begin{align*}
P(a,b)&=(a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)-(a^3+b^3)^2\\
&=a^4b^2-2a^3b^3+a^2b^4\\
&=a^2b^2(a^2-2ab+b^2)
\end{align*}

We consider the elementary symmetric polynomials in $2$ variables $a,b$:
\begin{align*}
e_1&=e_1(a,b)=a+b\\
e_2&=e_2(a,b)=ab
\end{align*}
We observe, that a factor of $P(a,b)$ is already given as symmetric polynomial
\begin{align*}
P(a,b)=e_2(a,b)^2\cdot(a^2-2ab+b^2)
\end{align*}
and we put the focus on 
\begin{align*}
f(a,b)=a^2-2ab+b^2
\end{align*}

> **The method:**
>   If it's obvious to represent $f(a,b)$ via elementary symmetric polynomials we are finished. Otherwise simplify $f(a,b)$ by setting the variable $b=0$. This *reduces the number of variables by one* and wie obtain a function
>   \begin{align*}
> q(a):=f(a,0)=a^2
> \end{align*}
>   Find a representation of the polynomial $q(a)$ as polynomial $Q(a)$ in elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1(a)=a$
>   \begin{align*}
> q(a)=Q(e_1(a))=e_1(a)^2=a^2
> \end{align*}
>   Consider the polynomial $g(a,b)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> g(a,b)=Q(e_1(a,b))=e_1(a,b)^2
> \end{align*}
>   Then 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{f(a,b)-g(a,b)}{e_2(a,b)}=\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2-(a+b)^2}{ab}=-4\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   is a polynomial of *lower total degree than $f$*. Now apply the method on this polynomial with lower degree.

Since the polynomial $-4$ is already simple enough, we can calculate $f(a,b)$  as

\begin{align*}
f(a,b)=-4e_2(a,b)+g(a,b)=-4e_2(a,b)+e_1(a,b)^2
\end{align*}

> We finally obtain a representation of OPs polynomial $P(a,b)$ according to (1) as polynomial of elementary symmetric polynomials
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(a,b)&=e_2(a,b)^2\cdot(-4e_2(a,b)+e_1(a,b)^2)\\
> &=-4e_2(a,b)^3+e_2(a,b)\cdot e_1(a,b)^2\\
> &=-4(ab)^3+(ab)^2(a+b)^2
> \end{align*}

---

> **Second example:** $f_1(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3$
>
> We show
>   \begin{align*}
> f_1(a,b,c)&=3e_3(a,b,c)-3e_2(a,b,c)e_1(a,b,c)+e_1(a,b,c)^3\\
> &=3(abc)-3(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^3
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate this slightly more complex example by  applying the method in *two steps*.

We consider the elementary symmetric polynomials in $3$ variables $a,b,c$:
\begin{align*}
e_1&=e_1(a,b,c)=a+b+c\\
e_2&=e_2(a,b,c)=ab+ac+bc\\
e_3&=e_3(a,b,c)=abc\\
\end{align*}

> **The method:**
>
> **Step $1$:**
>   It is not obvious to represent $f_1(a,b,c)$ via elementary symmetrical polynomials and so we apply the method by setting the variable $c=0$.
>   This *reduces the number of variables by one* and we obtain a function
>   \begin{align*}
> q_1(a,b):=f_1(a,b,0)=a^3+b^3
> \end{align*}
>
> **Step $2$:**
>   According to the method we should find a representation of the polynomial $q_1(a,b)$ as polynomial $Q_1(a,b)$ in elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1(a,b)$ and $e_2(a,b)$.
>
> Since we don't see a representation immediately, we consider $q_1(a,b)$ as polynomial $f_2(a,b):=q_1(a,b)$ and apply the first part of the method again.

$$$$

> We start with
>   \begin{align*}
> f_2(a,b)=a^3+b^3
> \end{align*}
>   We again reduce the number of variables by one and we obtain a function 
>   \begin{align*}
> q_2(a):=f_2(a,0)=a^3
> \end{align*}
>   Now it's easy to see, that $q_2(a)$ can be represented via the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_1(a)=a$
>   \begin{align*}
> q_2(a)=Q_2(e_1(a))=e_1(a)^3=a^3
> \end{align*}
>   We consider the polynomial $g_2(a,b)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> g_2(a,b)=Q_2(e_1(a,b))=e_1(a,b)^3=(a+b)^3
> \end{align*}
>   Then 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{f_2(a,b)-g_2(a,b)}{e_2(a,b)}=\frac{a^3+b^3-(a+b)^3}{ab}=-3(a+b)=-3e_1(a,b)\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   is a polynomial of *lower total degree than $f_2$*.

We observe according to (2)

\begin{align*}
f_2(a,b)=-3e_1(a,b)e_2(a,b)+g_2(a,b)=-3e_1(a,b)e_2(a,b)+e_1(a,b)^3\tag{3}
\end{align*}
We have *systematically* found a representation of $q_1(a,b)=f_2(a,b)$ as polynomial of elementary symmetric polynomials and go on with step 1.

> **Step $1$ continued:**
>
> Since $q_1(a,b)=a^3+b^3=f_2(a,b)$ we obtain according to (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> q_1(a,b)=-3e_1(a,b)e_2(a,b)+e_1(a,b)^3
> \end{align*}
>   we go on with defining
>   \begin{align*}
> g_1(a,b,c)&=-3e_2(a,b,c)e_1(a,b,c)+e_1(a,b,c)^3\\
> &=-3(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^3\\
> &=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{f_1(a,b,c)-g_1(a,b,c)}{e_3(a,b,c)}&=\frac{f_1(a,b,c)+3e_2(a,b,c)e_1(a,b,c)-e_1(a,b,c)^3}{abc}\\
> &=\frac{(a^3+b^3+c^3)-(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc_)}{abc}\\
> &=3\\
> \end{align*}
>   and we finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> f_1(a,b,c)&=3e_3(a,b,c)+g_1(a,b,c)\\
> &=3e_3(a,b,c)-3e_2(a,b,c)e_1(a,b,c)+e_1(a,b,c)^3\\
> &=3(abc)-3(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^3
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials says a symmetric polynomial of $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ can be written as a polynomial of $$\quad e_1 = \sum_i x_i,\quad e_2 = \sum_{i < j}x_ix_j, \quad \dots, \quad e_n = \prod_i x_i.$$

For example, symmetric polynomial $(a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)-(a^3+b^3)^2$ can be written as a polynomial of $x = a + b, y = ab$. In this example, inductively one can get $a^n + b^n$ in terms of $x,y$. Note that $$a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2-2ab = x^2-2y,$$ $$a^3 + b^3 = (a^2 + b^2)(a+b) - ab(a+b) = (x^2-2y)x - yx = x^3-3xy,$$ $$a^4+b^4 = (a^3+b^3)(a+b)-ab(a^2+b^2) = (x^3-3xy)x-y(x^2-2y)=x^4-4x^2y+2y^2.$$

Therefore we have $$(a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)-(a^3+b^3)^2 = (x^2-2y)(x^4-4x^2y+2y^2)-(x^3-3xy)^2 = x^2y^2-4y^3.$$

In general, once a symmetric polynomial is written in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials, it might be easier to observe factors. In this example, $x^2y^2-4y^3 = y^2(x^2-4y)$.

**Warning** One might want to substitute the original variables back to see if certain factors can be factorized further. In the example, $x^2-4y$ is irreducible, however $x^2-4y = a^2+b^2-2ab = (a-b)^2$ is reducible.

Comment: [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) trivializes this to some extent. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you another algoritm to find the factorization. I'll use your polynomial to show the way it works. For a polynomial in $k$ variables the algorithm can be described as:

1. Order the terms of your polynomial in lexicographic ordening.
2. Suppose the highest term is $X_{1}^{n_1}\cdots X_{k}^{n_k}$, then subtract $e_{1}^{n_1-n_2}e_{2}^{n_2-n_3}\cdots e_{k}^{n_k}$.
3. Remember this term and head back to step 1 with your new polynomial. If the new polynomial is zero, you are finished.
4. Add all the terms found to get your representation for the original polynomial.

I won't prove here that it works, I will just show you how to apply it. The lexicographic ordening means that we start with the term which has highest $n_1$, then if two have the same value for $n_1$ we choose the one with highest $n_2$ etc.

Your polynomial: $f = (a^4+b^4)(a^2+b^2)−(a^3+b^3)^2 = a^4b^2 -2a^3b^3+ a^2b^4$,  put in the lexicographic ordening. Next we create 
\begin{equation}f_1 = f - e_{1}^{4-2}e_{2}^{2} = f-(a+b)^2(ab)^2 = (a^4b^2-2a^3b^3+ a^2b^4) - (a^4b^2+2a^3b^3 + a^2b^4) = 0.
\end{equation}
Since this is zero we are done after one step and conclude that $f = f_1 + e_{1}^{4-2}e_{2}^{2} = 0 + e_{1}^{4-2}e_{2}^{2} = (a+b)^2(ab)^2$.

Comment: Interesting approach. Could you provide a reference? I'm aware of [this paper](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~vadim/Kuznetsov-Sklyanin.pdf) regarding factorizing *bases* of symmetric polynomials, which looks somewhat more complicated. Btw: I think $f_1=-4a^3b^3$, so the result is according to OPs expression: $(a-b)^2(ab)^2$. Best regards,

Comment: mmm.. apparently I made a mistake, I will get on it^^ The only reference I know for this algorithm unfortunately is in Dutch. Maybe you can still understand some parts? It's theorem 1.1 from http://gerard.vdgeer.net/alg3.pdf

Comment: Do you mean theorem (1.1) *Hoofdstelling van de symmetrische functies*? Please note, this theorem does not address the factorisation of symmetric polynomials, but instead the unique representation of symmetric polynomials via elementary symmetric polynomials. So, this is the *fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials*. You might try to apply it on my second example: $f(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Comment: oh geez, my bad. Totally misread the question. Oh well, anybody wanting to know anything about the unique representation of symmetric functions can read my answer...XD

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna add an easy way for readers: (it can be used in Projective Spaces in Algebraic Geometry)

First put $b=1$ (this is dehomogenize). Then $$(a^4+1)(a^2+1)-(a^3+1)^2=a^2(a^2+1-2a).$$ Now homoginize it to degree $6$: $$a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2ab).$$

Comment: This doesn't seem legit at all... Why would a factorization of the dehomogenized version lead to a factorization of the original?

Comment: you can rewrite it in projective space $(a:b)$ as $(a:1)$. Elemantry example:

$x^2-y^2=y^2((\frac xy)^2-1)$